# How to make Visual Studio close running process before performing build?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm building WinForms application using Visual Studio 2010. Every time I make a change in the code I have to run the application and check how it works. The problem is that I do this frequently and once I forget to close the previous instance of the application the compiler generates error "The process cannot access the file bin\Debug....". Is it possible to make Visual Studio close the running instance before performing build?

Comment: Start the program with F5.  You'll love the debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An idea: Make a pre-build step for the executable project that uses Taskkill to kill the process. Read more about Taskkill here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the following pre-build event command line "taskkill /im myImageName", and it worked for me.

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen i added the following pre-build event taskkill /IM "$(TargetFileName)" /F the problem is I got an error if the process is not running. any suggestions?

Answer (score 33):

Add the following to the projects Pre-build event (based on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7612967/18107)):

```
taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq $(TargetFileName)"
```

The command as used in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23084759/18107) may result in an error in cases where the process is not running.

This variation uses a filter (`/fi`) which does not 'fail' even if there is 0 matches.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Please note that you can also use wild card if desired. For instance...
 taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq MyHealthMonitor*"

Comment: I don't know if your VS works differently than mine but the "other answer" works just as well when the process is not running. The `exit 0` is responsible for ignoring errors, you know.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Morten's answer:

Use **taskkill** and then **ignore errors**.

```
taskkill /F /IM "$(TargetFileName)"
exit 0
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. @tpower 's solution below worked for me.

Comment: @ebol2000 It did work. But for debug version only. With `/f` option it kills both debug and release.

Answer (score 4):

Following code from another stackexchange answer worked for me.

wmic process where name='chromedriver.exe' delete

Comment: would you please link to that other answer so that we can see it?

Answer (score 0):

This works if $(TargetFileName) is a DLL.

```
taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq $(ProjectName).exe"
```